# Como criar um filtro a partir das palavras/frases de interesse para filtrar uma determinada vaga de uma "List"?

Tags: java, filtro

Em meu exemplo tenho duas classes que são `SetorInteresse` e `Vaga`, abaixo segue a estrutura das duas:

Classe SetorInteresse:

```
public class SetorInteresse {

    private List<String> setores;

    public SetorInteresse(List<String> setores) {
        this.setores = setores;
    }

    public SetorInteresse() { }

    public void addPalavra(String palavra) {  setores.add(palavra); }

    public void removePalavra(String palavra) { setores.remove(palavra); }

    public List<String> getSetores() { return setores; }
}
```

Classe Vaga:

```
public class Vaga {
    private String tituloVaga;
    private String setor;
    private String funcao;    

    public Vaga(String tituloVaga, String setor, String funcao) {
        this.tituloVaga = tituloVaga;
        this.setor = setor;
        this.funcao = funcao;        
    }

    public Vaga() { }   

    public String getDescricaoVaga() {
        return tituloVaga;
    }

    public void setDescricaoVaga(String tituloVaga) { this.tituloVaga = tituloVaga; }

    public String getSetor() { return setor; }

    public void setSetor(String setor) { this.setor = setor; }

    public String getFuncao() { return funcao; }

    public void setFuncao(String funcao) { this.funcao = funcao; }   
}
```

Abaixo possuo dois métodos um que popula a variável `vagas` de tipo `List<Vaga>` e o outro que popula o atributo `setores` do objeto `SetorInteresse` veja:

Método que popula a variável `vagas`:

```
List<Vaga> vagas = criaVagas();
...
static List<Vaga> criaVagas() { 
    List<Vaga> vagas = new ArrayList<>();
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Desenvolvedor Java", "Tecnologia da Informação", "Desenvolvedor"));       
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Desenvolvedor C# e Web", "Tecnologia da Informação", "Desenvolvedor"));
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Motorista Carreteiro", "Logistica", "Motorista"));       
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Gerente de Sistemas", "Tecnologia da Informação", "Desenvolvedor"));
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Estágiario Tecnologia da Informação", "Tecnologia da Informação", "Estágiario"));       
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Analista de Sistemas", "Tecnologia da Informação", "Analista"));              
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Suporte Técnico", "Suporte", "Suporte"));              
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Gerente Comercial", "Departamento Administrativo", "Gerente"));       
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Assistente de Recursos Humanos", "Recursos Humanos RH", "Aissistente"));       
    return vagas;
}
```

Método que popula o atributo `setores`:

```
SetorInteresse setorInteresse = criaSetorInteresse();
...
static SetorInteresse criaSetorInteresse() { 
    SetorInteresse setorInteresse = new SetorInteresse();
    setorInteresse.addPalavra("Desenvolvimento de programas");        
    setorInteresse.addPalavra("Tecnologia da informação e serviços");
    setorInteresse.addPalavra("Análise de sistemas");        
    return setorInteresse;
}
```

Com base nos dados que foram inseridos nas duas variáveis `vagas` e `setorInteresse` eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira em que eu poderia criar um filtro que me retorna-se apenas os objetos da lista `vagas` em que o valor do atributo `setor` do objeto `Vaga` se relacione com alguma das palavras ou frase do atributo `setores` ou se existe alguma alternativa para isso?

Exemplo, se eu possuo o seguinte valor em meu atributo setores:

> Desenvolvimento de programas

Eu obteria todos os objetos de tipo `Vaga` em que o valor do atributo `setor` esteja relacionado a `Desenvolvimento de programas`, neste caso as vagas que eu receberia seria:

> Desenvolvedor Java
>   Desenvolvedor C# e Web
>   Gerente de Sistemas
>   Estágiario Tecnologia da Informação
>   Analista de Sistemas
>   Suporte Técnico

Sendo assim as vagas exibidas seria de acordo com os interesses definidos no atributo `setores`.

Existe uma forma de criar um filtro que me retorne esses resultados ou existe alguma biblioteca que faça isso para mim. E também eu gostaria de saber quais critérios eu deveria definir na relação entre as palavras/frases e como defini-los, caso se for necessário fazer isso?

Comment: Para buscar de maneira inteligente provavelmente terá que fazer a consulta por similaridade, semelhante ao Google que da aquela mensagem: *"Você quis dizer ..."*. Primeiro teria que dividir a palavra com `split` e excluir palavras com 2 ou 3 caracteres (de, com, do, em), depois teria que usar um algoritimo para comparar palavra por palavra, como por exemplo o `levenshtein` ou `hamming`. As palavras nos setores teriam que todas encontrar similares em vagas, mas vagas pode ter palavras a mais, creio eu.

Comment: O filtro receberia um texto com o suposto setor a ser considerado ou o setor seria selecionado de opções pré-definidas? Pergunto isso porque se for a alternativa 2 tem uma forma bem mais elegante de resolver teu problema.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra a intenção é analisar o texto e colocar em um filtro após a analise, entretanto, se for muito complexo esta analise eu poderia definir algumas palavras para o filtro... estou buscando alternativas :)

Comment: Você tá usando Java 8? :P

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra sim, esqueci de mencionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O grande problema está no fato de que o relacionamento entre a vaga e o setor é essencialmente uma validação semântica, coisa na qual computadores não são muito bons. Contudo, dá pra se obter alguns resultados satisfatórios apenas com manipulação simbólica, algo no qual computadores são excelentes.

Assumindo que a descrição de um `SetorInteresse` é ao menos simbolicamente similar a um setor em uma vaga, poderíamos usar o algoritmo da distância de [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) pra calcular a similaridade entre o setor da vaga e o setor de interesse. Com isso poderíamos definir uma limite mínimo de similaridade aceitável e filtrar as vagas utilizando esse critério.

Um exemplo prático:

```
List<Vaga> vagas = criaVagas();

List<Vaga> filtered = vagas.stream().filter(
        v -> StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(department, v.getSetor()) <= DISTANCE_THRESHOLD
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Se o setor de interesse for `"Desenvolvimento de programas"` então as seguintes vagas são retornadas pra um limite de tolerância 20:

```
1. Desenvolvedor Java
2. Desenvolvedor C# e Web
3. Gerente de Sistemas
4. Estagiário Tecnologia da Informação 
5. Analista de Sistemas 
6. Gerente Comercial
```

O problema em tentar resolver esse problema apenas no nível sintático é que algumas strings podem ter menor distância ainda que seu valor semântico não tenha nada a ver com o esperado – como foi o caso da vaga de Gerente Comercial, cujo setor apresentou menor distância dentre todas.

Além disso, uma tolerância universal não vai ser muito eficiente. Muito provavelmente você terá que definir tolerâncias individuais pra cada departamento. Uma heurística possível é considerar a tolerância em função do tamanho das strings comparadas. Por exemplo, a distância de Levenshtein não pode ser igual a 80 ou 90 por cento do tamanho da maior string.

---

*O método que calcula a distância de Levenshtein, além de outros métodos pra distância de strings, está disponível na bilioteca Apache Commons Lang.*

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

Answer (score 6):

Como você está usando Java 8, você pode usar as [expressões lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). Um exemplo de como seria possível utilizá-las é:

```
List<Vaga> vagas = criaVagas();
List<Vaga> vagasFiltradas = vagas.stream().filter(vaga -> vaga.getSetor().contains("Tecnologia")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

O que o trecho acima faz é utilizar um filtro que pode ser definido como você quiser e ele será aplicado em todos os elementos da lista! O filtro que eu escolhi como exemplo mapeia um objeto "vaga" da `Collection` "vagas" e verifica se o setor dessa vaga é associado a um setor que você vai usar como filtro. A verificação procura se o campo setor da vaga possui a palavra "Tecnologia" em qualquer parte da `String`. Coloquei "Tecnologia" para ilustrar e então nesse caso iriam aparecer:

```
Desenvolvedor Java
Desenvolvedor C# e Web
Gerente de Sistemas
Estágiario Tecnologia da Informação
Analista de Sistemas
```

Esse filtro pode ser mais sofisticado, considerando por exemplo outras informações da vaga para limitar ainda mais os resultados.

Answer (score 3):

Minha orientação é você segmentar mais seu código criando 3 classes:

```
public class Setor {
    private int codigoSetor;
    private String descricaoSetor;


    ...gets and setters
}

public class Funcao {
    private int codigoFuncao;
    private String descricaoFuncao;


    ...gets and setters
}

public class Vaga {
    private String tituloVaga;
    private int codigoSetor;
    private int codigoFuncao;

    public Vaga(String tituloVaga, int setor, int funcao) {
        this.tituloVaga = tituloVaga;
        this.codigoSetor = setor;
        this.codigoFuncao = funcao;        
    }

    ...gets and setters
}
```

Crie setores funções e vagas com códigos identificadores:

```
SetorInteresse setorInteresse = criaSetorInteresse();

static boolean criaSetorInteresse() { 
    SetorInteresse setorInteresse = new SetorInteresse();
    setorInteresse.save(1, "Desenvolvimento de programas");        
    setorInteresse.save(2, "Tecnologia da informação e serviços");
    setorInteresse.save(3, "Logistica");
    ...

    return setorInteresse;
}

static String getSetorInteresse(int codigo) { 
    SetorInteresse setorInteresse = SetorInteresse();
    for (Setor setor : setorInteresse.getFuncoes()) {
        if (setor.getCodigoFuncao == codigo) {
            return setor.getDescricaoFuncao; 
        }
    }
}


FuncaoInteresse funcaoInteresse = criaFuncaoInteresse();

static boolean criaFuncaoInteresse() { 
    FuncaoInteresse funcaoInteresse = FuncaoInteresse();
    funcaoInteresse.save(1, "Desenvolvedor");        
    funcaoInteresse.save(2, "Estágiario");
    funcaoInteresse.save(3, "Motorista");    
    ...

    return funcaoInteresse;
}

static String getFuncao(int codigo) { 
    FuncaoInteresse funcaoInteresse = FuncaoInteresse();
    for (Funcao funcao : funcaoInteresse.getFuncoes()) {
        if (funcao.getCodigoFuncao == codigo) {
            return funcao.getDescricaoFuncao; 
        }
    }
}

List<Vaga> vagas = criaVagas();
...
static List<Vaga> criaVagas() { 
    List<Vaga> vagas = new ArrayList<>();
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Desenvolvedor Java", 2, 1));       
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Desenvolvedor C# e Web", 2, 1));
    vagas.add(new Vaga("Motorista Carreteiro", 3, 3));
    ...

    return vagas;
}
```

E quando querer utilizar as descrições utilize os métodos getSetorInteresse e getFuncao passando os códigos que foram relacionados com as vagas inseridas.

Comment: Gostei da resposta, porem, se eu tiver que associar código vou ter um problema na implementação, porque os dados vem de um arquivo XML e terei que ficar verificando código associado a um setor ou função sempre que add algo novo. Eu gostaria mesmo é de uma maneira de analisar as palavras/frases e verificar qual combina com qual.